# List<T> using inside a class

Tags: c#, list, class, generic-list

I found a code sample about using List inside a class.There are codes what i don't understand.Name and Description fields have value inside List defination but Album field have not a value.(

`new genre { Name = "Rock" , Description = "Rock music", Album?? }`

).Why?

```
public class Genre
{
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public string  Description { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public string  Title { get; set; }
    public decimal  Price { get; set; }
    public Genre  Genre { get; set; }
}

var genre = new List<Genre>
{
    new genre { Name = "Rock" , Description = "Rock music" },
    new genre { Name = "Classic" , Description = "Middle ages music" }
};

new List<Album>
{
    new Album { Title = "Queensrÿche", Price = 8.99M, Genre = genre.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock") },
    new Album { Title = "Chopin", Price = 8.99M, Genre = genre.Single(g => g.Name == "Classic") }
};
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The `Name` and `Description` values are set, while `Albums` is not. It's the same as `genre.Name = "Rock"; genre.Description = "Rock Music";` and no `genre.Albums = whatever`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This C# syntax is called `Object and Collection initializers`.

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx).

This syntax allows you to set properties that you have access to during initialization of the object or collection.

Answer (score 2):

Those are [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) which are used for quick initialization of properties. You don't need to initialize all properties, just the ones you need.

Answer (score 2):

Because the coder did not want to set its value. If you want add a statement to the end Album = new List(). You don't need to set all of the properties.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, the code sample is using [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx).  For Collections, the Initializer calls the collection's Constructor and then calls the .Add() function for each element listed inside the curly-braces.  For Objects, the Initializer calls the object's constructor and then sets values for any properties that you specified.

Object and Collection Initializers actually create your object or collection in a temp variable and then assign the result to your variable.  This ensures that you get an all-or-nothing result (i.e. if you can't get a partially initialized value if you access it from another thread during initialization).  The initialization code can be rewritten as follows:

```
var temp_list = new List<Genre>();
// new genre { Name = "Rock" , Description = "Rock music" }
var temp_genre_1 = new Genre();
temp_genre_1.Name = "Rock";
temp_genre_1.Description = "Rock music";
temp_list.Add(temp_genre_1);
// new genre { Name = "Classic" , Description = "Middle ages music" }
var temp_genre_2 = new Genre();
temp_genre_2.Name = "Classic";
temp_genre_2.Description = "Middle ages music";
temp_list.Add(temp_genre_2);
// set genre to the result of your Collection Initializer
var genre = temp_list;
```

Since this code does not explicitly set the value of the `Album` property of the genres, it gets set to the default value specified in your `Genre` class (which is null for reference types).